# function returns undefined value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function named `IsValidUrl()` that I need that returns some values by its situation(false or true). But inside of this function I have another function that won't let to pass the values to `IsValidUrl()`.

```
var validUrl = await isValidUrl();

if (!validUrl) {
  console.log(validUrl); ** //validUrl is undefined**

  return res.status(404).send('not found');
}

function isValidUrl() {

  Post.findOne({
    url: req.params.path
  }, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    } else if (!result) {
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  })
}
```

How can I send the returned values to the `IsValidUrl()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function isValidUrl() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Post.findOne({
      url: req.params.path
    }, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else if (!result) {
        resolve(false);
      } else {
        resolve(true);
      }
    })
  })

}
```

Comment: You must always explain what you change and why, just pasting a block of code without any explanation is not really helpful.

Comment: thanks!. it solved my problem